How is AES-128 still considered to be quantum resistant?
AES-128 if cracked using quantum computer, Grover’s algorithm will make it $2^{64}$ computations to complete.
The fastest non-quantum classical super computer can run approximately $2^{57}$ operations per second, so it would do the $2^{64}$ operations in less than a minute. And I believe the quantum computer would have even faster operation speed. How some people say AES-128 is still quantum-resistant?

The fastest classical computer gets to $10^{17}$ operations per second through massive parallelism - Grover's algorithm doesn't parallelize very well.

There's also the more minor point of a definition of 'operation'.  For the 'fastest classical computer', the operations cited as arithmetic ones, say, an addition or a multiplication of (say) 64 bit words.  For Grover, the operation would be an entangled AES operation (either compute or uncompute) - that would take quite a few logical or arithmetic operations to perform.  This is a constant factor difference, but large constant factors shouldn't be ignored.

Some calculations are here Does Grover's algorithm really threaten symmetric security proofs?

"... can run 10^17 operations per second, only less than a minute would crack the 2^64 operations." - It's a bit of a detail, but 2⁶⁴/10¹⁷ is about 184, so more than 3 minutes.

It is also a fallacy to think that quantum computers will perform operations faster than a classical computers. Both sorts of computation will require physical information moving at most at the speed of light traversing a physical gate. Grace Hopper's nanosecond still applies and to match classical speeds quantum gates would need to be reduced in size by many orders of magnitude. Consequently, the operation speed for current quantum computers is still at the kHZ level.

In short: you don't get the quantum advantage and a speedup, rather a slowdown as it is now.

This might be dupe of this Is AES-128 quantum safe?

To begin with, the threat from Grover (unlike Shor which does not apply to AES) does not lead to a subexponential algorithm, so doubling keylength is sufficient to address it.
More specifically, there are the issues of memory and the huge number of required qubits.
According to this paper by Grassl et al. the required number of quantum gates, depth of quantum circuits, and qubits for AES are as given below. We are currently very far away from such a computer.

Edit: Incorporated a crucial comment from @poncho in the answer for more context

The depth is the real killer. Anything that takes circa $2^{80}$
sequential operations will take, in practice, an infeasible amount of time. Yes, you can try to do things in parallel, but that dilutes the advantage you get from Grover's - for each halving of the time, you end up needing four times as many Quantum Computers. So, to get a T-depth of $2^{60}$
(that is, if each T operation takes a nanosecond, it'll still take over 30 years), you'd need circa $2^{40}$
= a trillion Quantum Computers.


The depth is the real killer.  Anything that takes circa $2^{80}$ sequential operations will take, in practice, an infeasible amount of time.  Yes, you can try to do things in parallel, but that dilutes the advantage you get from Grover's - for each halving of the time, you end up needing four times as many Quantum Computers.  So, to get a T-depth of $2^{60}$ (that is, if each T operation takes a nanosecond, it'll still take over 30 years), you'd need circa $2^{40}$ = a trillion Quantum Computers.

How long do you expect such computer that can crack aes128 like that on the table to be built? 20 years? IBM expected to reach 1 million qubits by 2030, google by 2029.

@poncho Are you saying that building such computer that can break aes128 not feasible?

@kag1357: unless technology advances considerably further than we expect it to, no, it would not appear to be feasible.

@kag1357 - Yeah... They aren't hitting a million qubits by 2030... what they "expect" to do is to pump their share prices. If you look at the state of the art of actual research, it's clear how unrealistic that is unless there's some paradigm shifting discovery

@kag1357 The number of qubits is kind of irrelevant here - the superconducting-qubit technologies that IBM and google are using can scale up very far (I am willing to believe they will have a million qubits by 2030), the issue is that currently the quality of their qubits is too low to support error-correcting codes (e.g the 6600 qubits mentioned above is error-corrected qubits, not physical qubits on the device, you would need tens of millions of those). There are other technologies which have higher quality qubits (i.e trapped ions) but they are much harder to scale up.

@TuomasLaakkonen: I'm not as sure that the superconducting qubit technology that IBM and Google are researching will scale up all that well.  The problem is the ultracold temperatures they require (10-15mK) and to do that, we use dilution refrigeration - that needs $He^3$ and we have a limited supply of that (and while we know how to make more, that's not a fast process)

@poncho that's a good point - I heard from a colleague who used to work on this that the issue is not the size of the silicon chip you'd have to cool (this is pretty small even for many qubits), but that they wouldn't have space to route all of the control wires without a room-sized dilution refrigerator. So perhaps they are banking on integrating the control systems into the silicon, it will be interesting to see if they can pull it off!

I'll break down a few incorrect assumptions in your question:

AES-128 if cracked using quantum computer, Grover’s algorithm will
make it $2^{64}$ computations to complete.

Here "computations" is doing a lot of work. What you mean is: $2^{64}$ coherent evaluations of AES encryption, done in superposition.  Each of these evaluations involves quite a few quantum operations: from one of the latest works (https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/683), about 100,000 operations in about 600-700 "cycles" (more on that later)

The fastest non-quantum classical super computer can run approximately
$2^{57}$ operations per second, so it would do the $2^{64}$ operations in less
than a minute.

This only works because classical super computers are massively parallel: they have enormous numbers of processors working simultaneously. Purely sequential clock speed in supercomputers topped out circa 2013 at around 3-5 Ghz.
As other comments mentioned, Grover parallelizes very badly. If you want it to find the answer twice as fast, you need 4x as many quantum computers. If you want the answer in less than 10 years, you need astronomical amounts of quantum hardware.

And I believe the quantum computer would have even faster operation speed.

I'm not sure why you believe this. Quantum computers won't just be better versions of classical computers. They will be able to do certain specialized tasks with fewer operations, but operations on quantum computers are more complicated. The main issue is noise: it is very hard to protect delicate quantum states.
In fact, with the most plausible approach today to protect against noise, each "cycle" in a quantum computer, as described above, will take many physical rounds of error correction to complete. Last time I did the numbers on this it was about 30 cycles per operation to keep the noise small enough for Grover's search.
So:

$2^{64}$ must be inflated to account for the number of quantum operations for each AES encryption
that number must also be inflated to account for the extra cycles of error correction
(maybe this number should also be inflated to account for quantum computers running slower than today's fastest classical computers, but let's be optimistic for a bit)
then that number needs to be inflated for the parallelism overhead.

When you account for all of this, the cost for a plausible quantum attack is around $2^{136}$ (compared to $2^{143}$ for the classical, measured at roughly the same level at detail). Both attacks are essentially impossible science fiction.
If you've got an hour, I recently gave a talk about this: https://youtu.be/eB4po9Br1YY, where I go through some of the details of the $2^{136}$ number.
